# Format to save value in DurationField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am unable to find that how I can set value of Duration Field in AdminPanel

> Lets say that I want to set that value to 1 year

So that latter I can get DurationField value and add it to datetime.datetime.now()

All I want to know is that in which format I 'll have to add value in Duration field from AdminPanel.

I know there is a method `my_model.duration = datetime.timedelta(days=20, hours=10)`

> But in my case Admin 'll have to add value from Admin Panel!!! So Please take time to understand question before marking it as a duplicate question

Comment: look at the last line of accepted answer, it describes the format to be used in admin panel input

Comment: Working, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For duration field you need to enter duration in format `DD HH:MM:SS.uuuuuu` where `uuuuuu` is microseconds. For for one year you need to enter `365 0` or `'365 0:0:0.000000'` or `365 0:0:0`(there are other possible combinations too). Don't enter just `365` it will consider it 365 seconds and 0 days.

```
>>> parse_duration('365')
datetime.timedelta(0, 365)
```

Internally Django uses the function `parse_duration` (`django.utils.dateparse.parse_duration`) to convert string to `datetime.timedelta`.

If you are unsure about what actual timedelta will be saved when you enter something in duration field in admin panel, open your favorite code editor and check the value you intend to enter:

```
>>> from django.utils.dateparse import parse_duration
>>> parse_duration('365 0')
datetime.timedelta(365)
>>> parse_duration('1 1:12:45.8979')
datetime.timedelta(1, 4365, 897900)
```